# How to bake a Bent Map (Object Space Normal) correctly with Cycles?

Tags: texture-baking

I am trying to bake a bent normal map with Blender Cycles but i get weird results by default. I mean it works but it's not the same colors as other map bakers like XNormal or Substance Painter, the texture looks like this:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to fix the axis of the baking option in the swizzle line because Blender uses different axis in the 3D viewport than other software. So you must use **+X +Z -Y**.

Also don't forget to reset the orientation by doing an "Apply" with the shortcut Ctrl + a then Apply Rotation.

[image]