# Possible to convert tangent-space normal map to object-space normal map, given obj + png?

Tags: mesh, texture-baking, normal-map

I have a 3d model as a .obj (with uv coordinates) and a tangent-space normal map as a .png.

Is it possible in Blender (using just this information as input) to write out a *object-space* normal as a .png?

Here's an example.

Given [this 3d model of a head as an .obj](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ssloy/tinyrenderer/master/obj/african_head/african_head.obj) and this tangent space/local/relative normal map:
[image: tangent space normal map]

I'd like to be able to bake out a object-space/global/world normal map like this:

[image: object space normal map]

Comment: Maybe use the bake settings discussed here: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/72663/how-to-bake-a-bent-map-object-space-normal-correctly-with-cycles